# Zabbix trigger of drop user

Tags: triggers, zabbix

My question : is it possible to have a trigger on that item that will be activated if there's a difference of xx% between the two last queries ?

Example :

```
Query at 01:00 -> 2000 users connected
Query at 01:10 -> 2100 users, difference is positive, we don't care
Query at 01:20 -> 2050 users, -50 users, around 2-3%, no big deal
Query at 01:30 -> 800 users, around 60% less connections, there's something wrong here
```

Is it possible to have a trigger that activates when the difference is, let's say, 20% negative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `abschange` [function](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/appendix/triggers/functions):

> The amount of absolute difference between last and previous values

to alert for both positive and negative changes.

Or you can use the `last` function to get the latest values you need:

> For example:
>
> last() is always equal to last(#1)
>
> last(#3) - third most  recent value (not three latest values)

In both cases you need to compute the % value in your trigger with the usual proportion:

`older_value:100 = newer_value:x`